# Hoverable boundary to match Draggable on Composable

Tags: android, kotlin, jetpack

I'm brand new to working with Jetpack Compose (and declarative UI in general) and can't for the life of me figure out how to do this.

I have the below composable that simply adds a handle to the side of the content to allow draggable resizing. The dragging aspect works exactly as expected, however, the hoverable element only triggers when the divider itself is being directly hovered over whereas there seems to be some outer boundary around the divider that is acceptable as a handle for dragging. What I'd like to do is have the hover logic apply when the draggable interaction is allowable, not just when the divider itself is beneath the mouse/pointer.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun HorizontalDraggable(
    content: @Composable() () -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    defaultWidth: Float = 0.3f,
    lowerWidth: Float = 0.15f,
    upperWidth: Float = 0.5f
) {

    BoxWithConstraints {
        val widthLimit = maxWidth
        var panelWidth by remember { mutableFloatStateOf(widthLimit.value*defaultWidth) }
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxHeight()
                .width(panelWidth.dp)
                .then(modifier)
            ,
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.End
        ) {
            content()
            val interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }
            val isHovered by interactionSource.collectIsHoveredAsState()
            Divider(
                color = (if (isHovered) LightSlateGray else BlackPearl),
                modifier = Modifier
                    .width(3.dp)
                    .fillMaxHeight()
                    .hoverable(interactionSource, true)
                    .draggable(
                        orientation = Orientation.Horizontal,
                        state = rememberDraggableState { delta ->
                            panelWidth = min(
                                max(panelWidth + delta, (widthLimit*lowerWidth).value),
                                (widthLimit*upperWidth).value
                            )
                        },
                        interactionSource = interactionSource
                    )
            )
        }
    }
}
```